# RDFS: can this statement be inferred?

Tags: types, rdf, rdfs, triplestore

If there exists an RDFS triple:

```
shop:Zara        rdfs:subClassOf        shop:Clothes
```

Can the statement:

```
shop:Zara        rdf:type               shop:Clothes
```

be inferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to extend a bit on Joshua's answer:

The following statement

```
shop:Zara        rdfs:subClassOf        shop:Clothes
```

implies that both `shop:Clothes` and `shop:Zara` are of type `rdfs:Class`.

In colloquial language, you could probably say:

> A Zara store is a clothing store.

but what you would actually mean with that is

> Any store that is a Zara store is a clothing store.

So in RDF it is true that from the statements

```
shop:Zara        rdfs:subClassOf        shop:Clothes
example:shopXYZ  rdfs:type              shop:Zara
```

the following can be inferred:

```
example:shopXYZ  rdf:type               shop:Clothes
```

Answer (score 2):

> If there exists an RDFS triple:
>
> ```
> shop:Zara        rdfs:subClassOf        shop:Clothes
> ```
>
> Can the statement:
>
> ```
> shop:Zara        rdf:type               shop:Clothes
> ```
>
> be inferred?

No.  Consider the analogy in set theory:

(1) A ⊆ B

does not imply

(2) A ∈ B

(1) says that every element of A is also an element of B. (2) says that A is an element of B.